# How to Capture App Uninstallation Events in Personal Conversations for a Teams Tab Bot in C#?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm working on a Teams tab bot using C# and the Bot Framework. I'm trying to capture the event when my app is uninstalled specifically within personal conversations. I've implemented the following code within my bot:

```
protected override async Task OnInstallationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInstallationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.Conversation.ConversationType == "personal")
    {
       
        var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference(); 
        
    } 
}
```

How do I detect user app uninstalling event (Uninstalling personal tab app)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To detect the event when your app is uninstalled specifically within personal conversations, you can use the `OnInstallationUpdateActivityAsync` method in your bot code. In this method, you can check the value of the action field in the installationUpdate event to determine if the app is being uninstalled.

```
protected override async Task OnInstallationUpdateActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInstallationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var activity = turnContext.Activity;
    
    if (activity.Action.Equals("remove", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && activity.Conversation.ConversationType.Equals("personal", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // App is being uninstalled in a personal conversation
        var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this code, we first check if the action field in the installationUpdate event is set to "remove" using a case-insensitive comparison. Then, we check if the conversationType is "personal" to ensure that the uninstallation is happening within a personal conversation.